# Liferay BatchUpdateException: Batch entry 0 insert into LayoutSet

Tags: postgresql, liferay, liferay-6

Looking for some help on following exception occurring on Production, find below configuration & error logs.

Same question is also posted on liferay forums, https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/55974594

I am using Liferay 6.2 EE SP10  with required clustering configuration tuned for production and also deployed Ehcache Cluster EE war.  with 2 liferay servers pointing to PostgresDB on master/slave configuration configured at  database side.

following are applicable portal-ext.properties around clustering or tuned setting,

```
# Clustering configuration
cluster.link.enabled=true
lucene.replicate.write=true
cluster.link.autodetect.address=DB IP: Port

# Ehcache Cluster EE app must be installed or cache replication will not work with this configuration
ehcache.cluster.link.replication.enabled=true
# Enables ehcache to use multicasting
net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName=/ehcache/hibernate-clustered.xml
ehcache.multi.vm.config.location=/ehcache/liferay-multi-vm-clustered.xml

# FileSystemStore nfs path to data folder
dl.store.impl=com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.store.AdvancedFileSystemStore
dl.store.file.system.root.dir=/opt/data/document_library
image.hook.file.system.root.dir=/opt/data/images
# Lucene indexes are maintained on individual servers, since NFS cluster aware is not available
#lucene.dir=/opt/data/lucene/
module.framework.base.dir=/opt/data/osgi

session.tracker.memory.enabled=false

plugin.repositories.trusted=
plugin.repositories.untrusted=
plugin.notifications.enabled=false

permissions.inline.sql.check.enabled=false

lucene.commit.batch.size=10000
lucene.commit.time.interval=300000
lucene.merge.factor=10
lucene.buffer.size=32
counter.increment=2000
counter.increment.com.liferay.portal.model.Layout=10
```

We have custom action that calls following API to apply site template to particular site based on group passed and site template id i.e. curLayoutSetPrototype.getLayoutSetPrototypeId()

```
SitesUtil.updateLayoutSetPrototypesLinks(group, 0L, curLayoutSetPrototype.getLayoutSetPrototypeId(), false, true);
```

Issue seems to be intermittent, Any idea what could be causing duplicate layoutset_pkey value?

```
13:41:09,049 ERROR [ajp-bio-8009-exec-131][JDBCExceptionReporter:82] Batch entry 0 insert into LayoutSet (groupId, companyId, createDate, modifiedDate, privateLayout, logo, logoId, themeId, colorSchemeId, wapThemeId, wapColorSchemeId, css, pageCount, settings_, layoutSetPrototypeUuid, layoutSetPrototypeLinkEnabled, layoutSetId) values (68054, 20157, '2015-06-30 13:41:08.659000 +01:00:00', '2015-06-30 13:41:08.659000 +01:00:00', '1', '0', 0, 'classic', '01', 'mobile', '01', '', 0, '', '7e6013a7-e209-43a5-a481-31b9f60066cc', '1', 68055) was aborted.  Call getNextException to see the cause.
13:41:09,050 ERROR [ajp-bio-8009-exec-131][JDBCExceptionReporter:82] ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "layoutset_pkey"_  Detail: Key (layoutsetid)=(68055) already exists. [Sanitized]
13:41:09,053 ERROR [ajp-bio-8009-exec-131][DefaultTransactionExecutor:93] Application exception overridden by commit exception
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update; SQL [insert into LayoutSet (groupId, companyId, createDate, modifiedDate, privateLayout, logo, logoId, themeId, colorSchemeId, wapThemeId, wapColorSchemeId, css, pageCount, settings_, layoutSetPrototypeUuid, layoutSetPrototypeLinkEnabled, layoutSetId) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:637)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateTransactionManager.java:793)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:664)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:754)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:723)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.DefaultTransactionExecutor.processCommit(DefaultTransactionExecutor.java:82)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.DefaultTransactionExecutor.execute(DefaultTransactionExecutor.java:70)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:51)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanAopProxy.invoke(ServiceBeanAopProxy.java:175)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy46.updateLayoutSetPrototypeLinkEnabled(Unknown Source)
    at com.liferay.portal.service.LayoutSetServiceUtil.updateLayoutSetPrototypeLinkEnabled(LayoutSetServiceUtil.java:88)
    at com.liferay.portlet.sites.util.SitesImpl.updateLayoutSetPrototypeLink(SitesImpl.java:1934)
    at com.liferay.portlet.sites.util.SitesImpl.updateLayoutSetPrototypesLinks(SitesImpl.java:1495)
    at com.liferay.portlet.sites.util.SitesUtil.updateLayoutSetPrototypesLinks(SitesUtil.java:348)
    at com.conv.portal.util.ConvSiteUtil.applySiteTpl(ConvSiteUtil.java:216)
    at com.conv.platform.usermanagement.service.OrganisationServiceImpl.createOrganisation(OrganisationServiceImpl.java:42)
    at com.conv.firmverification.service.FirmVerificationServiceImpl.approveFirm_aroundBody0(FirmVerificationServiceImpl.java:254)
    at com.conv.firmverification.service.FirmVerificationServiceImpl$AjcClosure1.run(FirmVerificationServiceImpl.java:1)
    at org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AbstractTransactionAspect.ajc$around$org_springframework_transaction_aspectj_AbstractTransactionAspect$1$2a73e96cproceed(AbstractTransactionAspect.aj:59)
    at org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AbstractTransactionAspect$AbstractTransactionAspect$1.proceedWithInvocation(AbstractTransactionAspect.aj:65)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
    at org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AbstractTransactionAspect.ajc$around$org_springframework_transaction_aspectj_AbstractTransactionAspect$1$2a73e96c(AbstractTransactionAspect.aj:63)
    at com.conv.firmverification.service.FirmVerificationServiceImpl.approveFirm(FirmVerificationServiceImpl.java:156)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2051.approveFirm(Unknown Source)
    at com.conv.firmverification.managedbeans.FirmVerificationManagedBean.approve(FirmVerificationManagedBean.java:505)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:183)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:161)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:228)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:297)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:101)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:786)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1251)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at com.liferay.faces.bridge.BridgePhaseResourceImpl.execute(BridgePhaseResourceImpl.java:103)
    at com.liferay.faces.bridge.BridgeImpl.doFacesRequest(BridgeImpl.java:128)
    at javax.portlet.faces.GenericFacesPortlet.serveResource(GenericFacesPortlet.java:178)
    at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:122)
    at com.liferay.portlet.ScriptDataPortletFilter.doFilter(ScriptDataPortletFilter.java:82)
    at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletFilterUtil.doFilter(PortletFilterUtil.java:71)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortletServlet.service(PortletServlet.java:112)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:486)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:411)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:338)
    at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invoke(InvokerPortletImpl.java:580)
    at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invokeResource(InvokerPortletImpl.java:675)
    at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.serveResource(InvokerPortletImpl.java:441)
    at com.liferay.portlet.PortletContainerImpl._doServeResource(PortletContainerImpl.java:792)
    at com.liferay.portlet.PortletContainerImpl.serveResource(PortletContainerImpl.java:152)
    at com.liferay.portlet.SecurityPortletContainerWrapper.serveResource(SecurityPortletContainerWrapper.java:166)
    at com.liferay.portlet.RestrictPortletContainerWrapper.serveResource(RestrictPortletContainerWrapper.java:166)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletContainerUtil.serveResource(PortletContainerUtil.java:164)
    at com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.processLayout(LayoutAction.java:386)
    at com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.doExecute(LayoutAction.java:200)
    at com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.execute(LayoutAction.java:95)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:431)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:236)
    at com.liferay.portal.struts.PortalRequestProcessor.process(PortalRequestProcessor.java:179)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:432)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.callParentService(MainServlet.java:549)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.service(MainServlet.java:526)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.secure.SecureFilter.processFilter(SecureFilter.java:293)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.jsoncontenttype.JSONContentTypeFilter.processFilter(JSONContentTypeFilter.java:42)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
    at com.conv.portal.filter.ConvVirtualHostFilter.doFilter(ConvVirtualHostFilter.java:174)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor618.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.bean.ClassLoaderBeanHandler.invoke(ClassLoaderBeanHandler.java:67)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1349.doFilter(Unknown Source)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:486)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:411)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:338)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.FriendlyURLServlet.service(FriendlyURLServlet.java:156)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.secure.SecureFilter.processFilter(SecureFilter.java:293)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.i18n.I18nFilter.processFilter(I18nFilter.java:243)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.etag.ETagFilter.processFilter(ETagFilter.java:86)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.jsoncontenttype.JSONContentTypeFilter.processFilter(JSONContentTypeFilter.java:42)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
    at com.conv.portal.filter.ConvVirtualHostFilter.doFilter(ConvVirtualHostFilter.java:174)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor618.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.bean.ClassLoaderBeanHandler.invoke(ClassLoaderBeanHandler.java:67)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1349.doFilter(Unknown Source)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:185)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:738)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:165)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:165)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:185)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at com.mulesoft.tcat.monitoring.tomcat.Tomcat55AgentValve.invoke(Tomcat55AgentValve.java:20)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.ha.session.JvmRouteBinderValve.invoke(JvmRouteBinderValve.java:218)
    at org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.ReplicationValve.invoke(ReplicationValve.java:333)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:193)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:268)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:184)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1216)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:383)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:133)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:656)
    ... 212 more
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Batch entry 0 insert into LayoutSet (groupId, companyId, createDate, modifiedDate, privateLayout, logo, logoId, themeId, colorSchemeId, wapThemeId, wapColorSchemeId, css, pageCount, settings_, layoutSetPrototypeUuid, layoutSetPrototypeLinkEnabled, layoutSetId) values (68054, 20157, '2015-06-30 13:41:08.659000 +01:00:00', '2015-06-30 13:41:08.659000 +01:00:00', '1', '0', 0, 'classic', '01', 'mobile', '01', '', 0, '', '7e6013a7-e209-43a5-a481-31b9f60066cc', '1', 68055) was aborted.  Call getNextException to see the cause.
    at com.edb.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement$BatchResultHandler.handleError(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:2827)
    at com.edb.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2237)
    at com.edb.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:700)
    at com.edb.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeBatch(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:2986)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeBatch(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:1135)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:70)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:268)
    ... 220 more
13:41:09,055 ERROR [ajp-bio-8009-exec-131][ConvSiteUtil:230] null
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update; SQL [insert into LayoutSet (groupId, companyId, createDate, modifiedDate, privateLayout, logo, logoId, themeId, colorSchemeId, wapThemeId, wapColorSchemeId, css, pageCount, settings_, layoutSetPrototypeUuid, layoutSetPrototypeLinkEnabled, layoutSetId) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
```

Appreciate for your help in advance..

Thanks.

Comment: You forgot to link where else on the internet you did ask the same question. *If* you crosspost, at least give us a hint (on *all* of the sites that you crossposted to) to minimize duplicate work when the other places are long solved

Comment: Sure Olaf, I have posted the same question on liferay forums, added link above, https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/55974594

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid the above mentioned issue, update the following property in portal-ext.properties. This should disable caching and get the counter value every time from database while inserting

```
counter.increment=1
counter.increment.com.liferay.portal.model.Layout=1
```

reference link for same issue in liferay [here](https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/56035684)